# Opening shapefile created in QGIS using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.6

I created a shapefile in QGIS but I am not able to open it in ArcGIS Desktop. It keeps saying open failed, error opening feature class. I saved it as an ESRI shapefile when creating it.

I am using ArcMap 10.6.1 and QGIS 2.18.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: If you created it in QGIS, why not continue working in QGIS? Also, you could try saving it in a different format using QGIS:

Comment: Please what format will you suggest? as I saved it as an ESRI shapefile.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to provide critical details, including the versions of QGIS and ArcGIS (though tagged 10.1, that release is ancient, having been retired more than 15 months ago), a description of the shapefile geometry type, number of features, and dBase attributes. Please also specify if you have moved the data at all (and what other files are in the same directory as the `.shp`

Comment: Arcmap 10.6.1 and QGIS 2.18. They are both  .shp

Comment: Did you move the shape-file to a different folder?

Comment: No I did not. I went to the same folder where they were created and tried to open them in ArcGIS but it would not open.

Comment: Does the file still open in QGIS?

Comment: yes the file opens in QGIS

Comment: Can you show us details of the files that make up the Shapefile - ie the .shp, the .shx, and the .dbf and any other files? On Windows, show a screengrab of the folder view with details such as the size of the files. If possible share your shapefile with us somehow. Also, try saving as another format, such as a GeoPackage (if your Arc can read GeoPackages)

Comment: Shapefiles created by QGIS should be fully compatible with the specification https://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf. Create a small shapefile that shows the problem, zip it and put it available for downloading.

Comment: A shapefile is not a *single* file -- It is a collection of at least three, as many as dozens of files with the same prefix and different suffixes. When you state "They are both .shp" it gives the impression that the .dbf and .shx are missing (and .prj, ...).  This is why you are being asked to list the files and their sizes.

Answer (score 1):

This is a long shot (I don't use ArcGIS), but is the shapefile still open in QGIS?  I don't know whether ArcGIS tries to write anything to the shapefile when it opens it, but might there be a permissions issue here?

If so, try closing QGIS.  Does ArcGIS still generate an error?

Other things you could try:
Copy the Shapefile to another location.  Does that version open in ArcGIS?
Run Fix Geometries on your Shapefile in QGIS, then retry in ArcGIS.